# ng2-cordova-oauth LinkedIn integration is not working with IONIC 3

Tags: ionic3, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate LinkedIN in my application and I am using IONIC3. I am following
this https://medium.com/@vivek040997/how-to-implement-linkedin-oauth-2-0-login-in-ionic-4-dd892e792d6a
to do integration. But this is working only with IONIC4 Application. As I am using IONIC 3 , it is not working.

```
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http/ngx";
constructor(public http: HTTP) {

  }
  getAccessToken(authCode) {
    const body = {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: authCode,
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost/callback",
        client_id: "myclientid",
        client_secret: "myclientsecretid"
    };

    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    };

    return this.http.post(
        "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
        body,
        headers
    );
}
```

Below is my code to get access token.But I am getting below error.
**error TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at HTTP.post(vendor.js)**
Can anyone please help me how to do this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
 import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http/ngx";
```

to this

```
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http";
```

**Edit 2**

remove ionic native http

```
 npm uninstall  --save @ionic-native/http
```

and install this version

```
npm install @ionic-native/http@4.9.0
```

Comment: After changing I am getting compile error in app.module.ts 
Type 'HTTPOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. @AbdulAzeem

Comment: in app.module.ts also remove  /ngx

Comment: yes I have removed /ngx. After that in providers section in module.ts am getting that error.Type 'HTTPOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.

Comment: the issue is that you must have installed latest version of ionic-native http

Comment: downgrade to version compatible